# I am trying to make a regex pattern to match the second appearance of a (firstname_lastname) on a line in a file

Tags: regex, awk

```
Hour AM/PM      BlackJack_Dealer    Roulette_Dealer      Texas_Hold_EM_dealer

12:00:00 AM    Izabela Parrish Marlene Mcpherson    Madina Britton
```

I tried easing the readability, i know it's bad and i apologize. THERE ARE SPACES BETWEEN FIRSTNAME_LASTNAME JUST DIDNT WRITE IT THERE AS WELL.

So ideally, my regex pattern will capture "Marlene Mcpherson". From this example, the first (firstname_lastname) is followed by a single space which is then followed by Marlene.

This would be easier for me if every line was constructed this way, BUT some lines in the file I am using are formatted in a way that a tab may precede the second (firstname_lastname) for example:

```
12:00:00 PM    Summer-Louise Hammond    John-James Hayward    Katey Bean
```

So the names appear followed by spaces sometimes, followed by tabs sometimes, but each name is only separated by a single space, so that is how I know there should be some kind of pattern to identify, just comes down to a matter of getting the pattern syntax right. I know that there are hard fixes out there to find given names and such, but I am trying to make a generic script with "awk" to output the second names in these files.

I have tried :

```
awk '/([A-Za-z]\s+[A-Za-z])/' filename
```

and this feels like the closest I have gotten. I was trying to use {2} after the pattern to grab the occurence after the pattern, but wasn't able to get it to work. I also was trying out \K to ignore patterns before the desired pattern but that didn't seem to work either.

when executing grep -V, the machine has grep (GNU grep) 3.1

I am working with an ubuntu virtual machine and this is a homework assignment if that matters. I am learning about regex and grep right now in a bootcamp that I am enrolled in. Figured I would post it here as I wait for responses on our group slack, as it is 1 am.

Comment: hint:  no matter whether the names are separated by tabs or spaces, the second person's name on a line will be the fifth (`$5`) and sixth (`$6`) _fields_ when separated by _whitespace_.  Try `man awk`.

Comment: I feel you just need `awk '{print $5" "$6}' filename`

Comment: Are the columns actually fixed width, space padded? Then you can infer the width of each column, then extract whatever tokens are in those character positions. This will probably yield much higher precision than successively bumping into all the various [falsehoods programmers believe about names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Comment: If they are fixed-width, look into GNU awk's `FIELDWIDTHS` variable.

Comment: thank you for the response I took all the feedback greatly from everyone's answers and got a further in my problem, I appreciate it very much

Answer (score 2):

This is a job for awk if you don't use regexps, or sed if you do. It's not a good use for grep since grep is just for matching a regexp and printing what it finds (`g/re/p` = **G**lobally match a **R**egular **E**xpression and **P**rint the result), not for modifying what it finds (yes GNU grep with -P and some other fluff can do that but it's not useful since we already have that capability portably with a POSIX sed).

Using any POSIX sed:

```
$ sed -n 's/[0-9]\([^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]*\)\{4\}\([^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]*\).*/\2/p' file
Marlene Mcpherson
John-James Hayward
```

The above was run on this input file and doesn't care which spaces are tabs or blanks:

```
$ cat file
Hour AM/PM      BlackJack_Dealer    Roulette_Dealer      Texas_Hold_EM_dealer
12:00:00 AM    Izabela Parrish Marlene Mcpherson    Madina Britton
12:00:00 PM    Summer-Louise Hammond    John-James Hayward    Katey Bean
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if your fields are separated by tabs and / or spaces, awk will correctly assign the fields to the correct field identifier.

Given:

```
$ s=$(printf 'Hour AM/PM      BlackJack_Dealer    Roulette_Dealer     Texas_Hold_EM_dealer
12:00:00 AM    Izabela Parrish Marlene Mcpherson    Madina Britton
12:00:00 PM    Summer-Louise Hammond\tJohn-James Hayward    Katey Bean')
```

So long as your fields do not have spaces in them (that humans could understand but awk won't) you can do:

```
$ echo "$s" | awk '/^[[:digit:]]{2}:/{printf "%s %s\n", $5, $6}'
Marlene Mcpherson
John-James Hayward
```

With GNU grep, you could do:

```
$ echo "$s" | grep -oP '^[\d:]+\h+(AM|PM)(\h+\S+){2}\h+\K\S+\h+\S+'
Marlene Mcpherson
John-James Hayward
```

Either of these approaches will fail with names that have extra spaces in them, such as `Lee Harvey Oswald` or `Col. Muammar Gaddafi` or `John James Hayward`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small Gnu `awk` script. Gnu `awk` is the standard Linux `awk` (including Ubuntu)

If you want all second name in one line, comment/remove the second print line.

But a single `grep` and `awk` combination is simpler, if allowed to output a second name in each line.

```
$ grep  -Eo "[^[:space:]]+ [^[:space:]]+" input.txt | awk '!/[AP]M/{print $2}'
Parrish
Mcpherson
Britton
Hammond
Hayward
Bean
```

#### script.awk

```
BEGIN {                        # Preprocess section, runs only once
  FPAT = "[^[:space:]]+ [^[:space:]]+"; # Gnu awk variable FPAT, regexp to identify field data
                               # regexp to identify non-spaced-string space non-spaced-string
}

NR>1 {                         # For every line not the first line.
  for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {  # loop found fields, from 2nd field
    split($i, namesArr);       # split current field to namesArr array, by space seperator (default)
    printf("%s ", namesArr[2]);# second name in current field, appended to output line
  }
  print "";                    # start a new line
}
```

#### running

```
awk -f script.awk filename.txt
```

#### result from input

```
$ awk -f script.awk filename.txt
Parrish Mcpherson Britton
Hammond Hayward Bean
```